# ¿Cómo puedo descargar java netbeans 8.2?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

Desde hace algunas semanas atrás he querido descargar netbeans 8.2 ya que lo solicitan en mi universidad, pero en la página de oracle me sale un error y quería preguntar por alguna sugerencia para poder descargar el JDK junto con el IDE de Netbeans 8.2[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: compañero buenas tardes, vaya sorpresa que me pasó lo mismo, me puse a validar en internet haber que encontraba, encontre un video en youtube subido hace 1 mes, no tenia tantas visitas y me preocupe por el link, pero valide y en el video la persona lo descargaba directamente de la pagina de oracle, al detallar el navegador que utilizaba me di cuenta que era edge, entonces deduje que algun problema debe tener oracle para descargarlo, probé con edge ( navegador actualizado de internet explorer en w10) y vaya sorpresa si logré descargarlo, prueba y me cuentas, espero haber sido de ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segun veo tú URL de descarga no es correcta, la URL correcta para descarga es:

> https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.2/rc/

El IDE ya trae su JDK cuando se instala, pero lo recomendable es que descargues la JDK por aparte y la instales para que aprendas el proceso de crear las variables de entorno y agregar los binarios al path.

Actualmente la mejor opción de JDK es que utilices OpenJDK la del proyecto AdoptOpenJDK https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html porque con los cambios de licencias de Oracle desde la JDK 8u221 ya no es gratuita para proyectos, aunque se puede utilizar sin pagar estarías infringiendo la licencia, te dejo una guia en español de como se instala la JDK lo único que cambia es la URL de instalación según que versión elijas:

> https://parzibyte.me/blog/2020/04/03/instalar-openjdk-windows/

> Nota: A fecha de 22 de marzo del 2021 Oracle ya no tiene disponible el binario de Netbeans 8.2, se recomienda utilizar la versión de la `Apache Software Fundation` que ya tiene un proyecto maduro con todas las funcionalidades implementadas y que será la continuación del proyecto.

Comment: Sólo añado: La exigencia de licencia comercial con el JDK de Oracle es para entornos productivos. El problema es entonces que uno compile y pruebe con uno y despliegue con otro.

Comment: Si, de hecho el problema es llevarlo a un un producto o servicio en producción, si la idea es un proyecto de prueba o escolar no tendrías problemas, pero con las actuales alternativas no veo porque optar para estos casos por Oracles a menos que quieras un soporte pagado.

Comment: Nunca deberíamos usar cosas de Oracle pero shhhhh... :P

Comment: En el caso de netbeans 8.2 para linux no hay un repo oficial disponible, pero lo puedes descargar desde aqui http://www.cs.tohoku-gakuin.ac.jp/pub/Tools/NetBeans/8.2/